# DbUpdateException being thrown for unknown reason

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following entity objects (database version on right):

```
Invoker                
(N) Commands

Command                    
(1) Event             EventId(FKEY) 
(N) Effects               
(N) Conditions
--Other members

Effect
(1) EffectType        EffectTypeId(FKEY)
(N) Properties        CommandId(FKEY)
(N) Conditions
--Other members

                      CommandConditions: ConditionId(PKEY, FKEY), CommandId(FKEY)    
                      EffectConditions: ConditionId(PKEY, FKEY), EffectId(FKEY)                              

Condition
(1) ConditionType         
(N) Properties

                      EffectProperties: PropertyId(PKEY, FKEY), EffectId(FKEY)
                      ConditionProperties: PropertyId(PKEY, FKEY), ConditionId(FKEY)

Property
Name
Value
```

When I want to update an existing invoker entity, I do it like this:

```
public void UpdateInvoker(Invoker existingInvoker, InvokerViewModel contract, MyEntities context)
{
    //typeof(Invoker.Command = CommandViewModel
    existingInvoker.Commands = contract.Commands.Select(c => c.ToDataCommand(context)); 
}

public Command ToDataCommand(MyEntities context)
{
        var command = context.Commands.Create();
        command.CommandEvent = context.Events.First(e => e.EventName == Event.Name);
        command.CommandConditions = Conditions.Select(c => c.ToDataCondition(context)).ToList();
        command.CommandEffects = Effects.Select(e => e.ToDataEffect(context)).ToList();
        context.Commands.Add(command);
        return command;
}
```

The same setup used to generate the commands is used to generate the effects, conditions, and property entities as well.  When I commit this transaction, I receive a somewhat unhelpful DbUpdateException:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key.

But how could this setup create entities with matching keys?  Does entity framework not work well when an entity has a PKEY and FKEY on the same column?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem lies with entity framework not liking a foreign key and a primary key being on the same column.  Removing this fixed my issue.